# Google apps-script gmail threads and messages in threads behaviour

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I am missing something but cannot figure what.

Here is the code.

```
  function parseEmails(thread) {
    Logger.log(thread.getMessages());
}

function myFunction() {
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  threads.forEach(parseEmails);
}
```

If a single message from a thread is deleted it will still be loaded in a thread.getMessages().

I've tested this by manually deleting a message from a thread.And running a script.

Comment: I've tried to set Conversation view to off just to to see what will I get but the result is the same.

Comment: Deleted? Or **trashed**?

Comment: In gmail web, I use "Delete this Message"
In script message.moveToTrash();

Comment: A trashed message is by definition not deleted. So it will still appear as a part of `thread.getMessages()`, because it still exists on the server. Look at the methods associated with `GmailMessage` and you'll find you can still do what you want.

Comment: @tehhowch I would gladly accept your answer if you post it. Ofcorse I did not read all methods. isInInbox() is what I am looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Your question as-written isn't really answerable (there isn't a real question in it that I could find). If you edit it to include an [answerable question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then sure, I can write an appropriate answer.

Comment: @tehhowch I am sorry but I have missed your comment about answerable question. If you just add your comment as an answer why should not that be sufficient? I will still mark it as answer because it is.